# Footer compatibility compared between IE and Google Chrome won't Compromise

Tags: html, css, screen, footer

In my code, my footer will display at the bottom of my page, with no space above or below, as long as I specify a height of my page within Google Chrome. I tried doing height: 100% and so forth but still had problems.

When comparing that to my IE 11, the footer with a specified height has space below it. I can't seem to get both browsers to compromise and I have tried various options to make them both work.

My current css code that would affect the footer is as shown:

```
html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        min-width: 768px;
        /*keeps footer at bottom of page for IE 11 */
        display: flex;

    }

    /* Formating for body of Web Site */
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    body {
     font-family: times new roman;
     background-color: #ebebeb;
     zoom: 75%;
     /*keeps footer at bottom of page for IE 11 */
     width: 100%;
     background-postion: 50% 80%;

     }

     #screen {
     /* This locks everything in place*/
     top:0px;
     margin: 0 auto; 
     width:1500px;
     height: 1500px;
         padding-top:0;
         padding-bottom: 30px;
         postion: absolute;
     margin-left: 70px;
     margin-bottom: 0;

     }

 /* footer formating  */
    #footer {

        background-color: black;
        height: 40px;
        width: 1500px;
        color: white;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: relative center;
        bottom: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left:70px;
    }
```

My html:

```
<html>
<div id = "screen">
 <body>


 ............................................. other code

<div id = "footer">
        Copyright Notice - Site Maintanence by **********
        <br>
        Author of Published Text Content: ************<br>

        <a href = "#">Pagetop</a>

</div> <!-- end footer -->

</div> <!-- end screen format -->

 </body>

</html>
```

What IE looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if i got you right, you want the footer to "stick" the upper part of the website in both Chrome and IE11 browsers. 
i'm not sure why you chose this CSS settings because you didn't supply a link to the full website so i don't know exactly what is going on, but, you can get what you want not just on this two, but in all the browsers, the key is in the structure and the CSS, let me show you.

first of all i arranged your HTML and CSS so it will be easier to read and folow, i also deleted not needed code parts but you can do a reference with the old code to see the changes.

the `<div id="screen">` element was outside the `<body>` tag, so i put it in.

as you can see in the HTML code, i've put `<div id="leftcol">` and `<div id="centercol">` elements with "lorem ipsum" text to Illustrate the situation in your website. i assumed `<div id="screen">` is the website wrapper so i wrapped it all inside it.

```
<div id="screen">
    <div id="leftcol">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div id="centercol">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>  
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        Copyright Notice - Site Maintanence by **********
        <br />
        Author of Published Text Content: ************
        <br />  
    </div> <!-- end footer -->
    <div class="center">
        <a href = "#">Pagetop</a>
    </div>    
</div> <!-- end screen format -->
```

you can see in the CSS i've deleted unnecessary code like i said before, the key is to keep the things simple unless you have to make it complicated for some reason, if you will tell me the reason you need the `<HTML>` element with `display: flex;` or `<div id="screen">` element with `position: absolute;` i will try to help you with this and solve the problem but otherwise, let's keep it simple:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html
{
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

body
{
    font-family: times new roman;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    background-postion: 50% 80%;
}

#screen
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer
{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.center
{
    text-align: center;
}

#leftcol
{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background: #B4B4B4;
}

#centercol
{
    width: 60%;
    float: right;    
    background: #fff;
}

#leftcol, #centercol
{
    padding: 2%;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;   
}
```

that's way it's working in all of the browsers include old versions of IE.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvrcw4vw/3/

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. I do agree my code started getting a little uncontrolled because I was trying to find different ways to control it. Also the screen id is indeed the wrapper. I also was trying to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the page for all browsers. I will make sure later on to check my website in comparison to your example. Will keep ya posted.

Comment: I also used the flex because it was an example I found that would help keep the footer on the bottom of the page. Position absolute was another example i found to help control the page as well.

Comment: If i didn't use those, the footer always showed right below the header behind all the boxes of text containers.

Comment: you welcome, i'm not sure it will fix the problems on your website for 100% because i don't see the whole code and setting so i can't predict what will happen. if you will have problem with your websites after the changes then show me the whole code / try to upload the website to a server so i will see it on live and will be able to help you better.

Comment: i don't know from where did you take the examples but they don't fit to your situation here. i suggest you will read about CSS code you are going to use before you are using it because it will help you understand what is it for and you will be able on your own to know if it will fit to your website or not.